# Nodejs terminal script problematic cygwin paths of arguments - cannot make an universal script

Tags: node.js, shell, cygwin, windows-10, shebang

I have an issue with using node.js as a script language in the Cygwin terminal. The script is used not only on Cygwin, but also on other platforms like OS X or GNU/Linux (no issue there).

Local or absolute path arguments to the script are passed as Cygwin paths (example: `/cygdrive/c/Users/username/Dir/some-file.txt`), but node requires Windows path (example: `C:\Users\username\Dir\some-file.txt`).

There is a tool *cygpath* that is used to translate between the two, but because of the multiplatform requirement, I cannot hardcode them. I would not like to make any bash wrappers so I can keep it a one file script.

For example this would work: `./script $(cygpath -w /tmp/file)`, but I cannot require the users of the script to put cygpath every time they want to use it.

Node is installed as the windows binary and is invoked with a shabang: `#!/usr/bin/env node`. `which nodejs` yields `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/node`.

TL;DR: is there any sane and portable way to trigger automatic path translation in Cygwin for arguments of a nodejs script?

Comment: Your basic problem is that you are mixing cygwin executables with windows executables. There are two solutions: find a cygwin version of nodejs or find a non-cygwin version of bash i.e. a windows version of bash or create windows versions of each script file, e.g. a `script.bat`

Comment: I do know that, but cygwin version of nodejs has other issues, so I must use the windows one. Non-cygwin bash will break other things. I didn't want to use wrappers, but it looks like I might have no choice in that matter.

Comment: About cygwin version of nodejs -
 there isn't any! They [stopped supporting the platform long long ago](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Installation#building-on-cygwin). This kind of explains why everything had issues running when I tried using cygwin's nodejs some time ago...